# QGIS Network analysis/routing module

Tags: qgis, routing, network-analysis

in QGIS I have to draw a scheme ( kind of CAD) that represents electrical circuits.
The scheme consists of points and lines elements, with alphanumeric attributes associated.

The starting point and the ending point are connected by 1 or more lines, drawn with snap (there are intermediate points).
For example:

CIRCUIT A:
 X--------------------------X-------------X---------X
P1          L1              P2    L2      P3   L3   P4

​CIRCUIT B:​
​ X-------------------X-------------X
P5          L4       P6    L5      P7

This is an examples of my net:

[image]

Having selected the starting point only, I would like to determine what is the set of lines that make the connection and eventually what is the ending point.

In QGIS are there "native" network analysis / routing functions or plug-ins for network analysis?

I currently use QGIS 3.0 but I could eventually install a previous version if needed.

Comment: As a first hint: QGIS 2.18 -  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html and https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html?highlight=network

Comment: Hello Stefan and thanks for your support. I installed QGIS v. 2.18 and I use Road graph plug-ins. The problem is that the plug-ins require n. 2 points: start and end point. My needs is to have start point only. Please could you suggest me a solution? Thanks

Comment: Please add some more information about your data: 1. How is the data stored (shapefile, text-files, etc.)? In which way are geometries/features stored (linestrings, multilinestrings, etc.)? Which other attributes are describing your features? If it is possible, please add a meaningful picture (e.g. of the QGIS Canvas).

Comment: Hello Stefan, actually data is stored in shapefile (line and point); I have only one attribute: ID

Comment: This could also be interesting for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86613/counting-number-of-lines-connected-to-point